# how to add two button on trailing section of list tab flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want two buttons on trailing of list tab but buttons are overflow also i want to increase the list tab height and i don't want to decrease the button sizes here is the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRJ7S.png)

here is my code

```
 TabBarView(
            controller: _tabcontroller,
            children: <Widget>[
             // Text("HEllofghgfhgfhgfhgfh"),
              ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(

                    elevation: 6.0,
                    child: ListTile(

                      leading:  Container(
                          height: 70,
                          width: 80,
                          child: Image.network(
                              "https://smartbasket.pk/image/cache/data/Bazaarapna/dairy%20product/Haleeb%20Milk%20%E2%80%93%2001%20Litre%20(Pack%20of%2012)-500x500.jpg",
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      trailing: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: (){},
                            child: Text('Subscription'),
                          ),
                          RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: (){},
                            child: Text('Subscription'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      title: Text("Product Name"),
                      subtitle: Text("1 Liter \n\n RS, 115"),
                      isThreeLine: true,
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
             Text('1'),
              Text('2'),

            ],
          ),
```

Comment: You can use a row instead of ListTile.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your two buttons with `Expanded` Widget. What `Expanded` do is expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

Comment: When i wrap the second button overlap on first one

Comment: Just Add `SizedBox(height: 8)` in middle of it